# pgAdmin 4 - Can't do anything after connection lost

Tags: pgadmin, pgadmin-4

I'm using pgAdmin 4.5 on Windows 10.

When I connect to a database, things going well. Then after some idle time, pgAdmin says "The connection is lost", then refuse to do anything, **including Disconnect Server**. When I try to disconnect, it pops a toast at right bottom corner says "The connection is lost". The only solution is to restart pgAdmin, but it's slow and wierd.

This problem did not appear in pgAdmin 3. How can I reconnect to the database after the connection is lost, without restarting pgAdmin?